# How i get the params id from url using server side components in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to fetch an API but it's only working on the server side, so I need my component to be server-side, but all the hooks I found to get the url id are client side, is there one that allows it?

I've already tried useSearchParams, useRouter and nothing, here's the component I'm trying to run.

```
import FerramentaCard from '@/components/ferramentas/ferramenta';

export default async function Ferramenta() {
  const response = await fetch(`https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/items/${query.id}/data`, { method: 'GET', mode: 'no-cors' });
  const ferramentaInfo = await response.json();

  return <FerramentaCard ferramentaInfo={ferramentaInfo} />;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use fetch on a server-side component because it isn't working on the client-side? How are you trying to fetch data from a client-side component?

Comment: Add `context` in the parameter of the function like `export default async function Ferramenta(context)`. The context may contain the data.

Comment: @PratyayBiswas I tried to add context but didn't work, are undefined.

Comment: @GabrielCard i used the useEffect hook, but for some reason the api don't return nothing when the component is client side if you want trie the API is https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/items/T3_2H_TOOL_AXE/data i don't know if something about cors o something else.

Comment: What I recommend you use is a client component that does a fetch that goes to your server component and there you could try to do this fetch, for your situation the folder structure will be something like:
Client side: fetch("[...]/folder/[id]") and in the server component you will get the id as parameters.
So your server component can retrieve the data you want.

Comment: @GabrielCard i tried man, buts is not working, if the component be client side the api dont return nothing, i dont now what is happening.